# Elasticsearch: No feature for name [myitem]

Tags: elasticsearch

I get the following info about the index:

```
curl -XGET 'http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:9200/_cat/indices?v'

health status index                      pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   news_abc                   1   1    8983616      3008123      6.5gb          6.5gb
```

It seems that there is a data. Then I want to retrieve some data. For this I run this code:

```
curl -XGET 'http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:9200/news_abc'
```

and get the following result:

```
{"news_abc":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"myitem":{"include_in_all":false,"properties":{"audience":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"author":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"author_signature":{"type":"string","store":true,"analyzer":"generic_text_field","include_in_all":false},"body":{"type":"string","store":true,"term_vector":"with_positions_offsets","analyzer":"generic_text_field","include_in_all":false},"channel_name":{"type":"string","store":true,"fields":{"sort":{"type":"string","analyzer":"sortable_text_field"}},"analyzer":"generic_text_field","include_in_all":false},"client":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"cluster":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"creation_time":{"type":"date","store":true,"format":"date_time","include_in_all":false},"expanded_outbound_link":{"type":"string","store":true,"fields":{"raw":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}},"analyzer":"url_text_field","include_in_all":false},"hashtag":{"type":"string","store":true,"analyzer":"lowercase_keyword","include_in_all":false},"is_supplement":{"type":"boolean","store":true},"klout_score":{"type":"short","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"language_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"media_type":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"project":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"publication_date":{"type":"date","store":true,"format":"date_time","include_in_all":false},"publishing_platform":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"remote_code":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"remote_media_code":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"scope":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"source_country_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"source_name":{"type":"string","store":true,"fields":{"sort":{"type":"string","analyzer":"sortable_text_field"}},"analyzer":"generic_text_field","include_in_all":false},"source_rank":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"source_region_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"source_url":{"type":"string","store":true,"term_vector":"with_positions","analyzer":"url_text_field","include_in_all":false},"summary":{"type":"string","store":true,"term_vector":"with_positions_offsets","analyzer":"generic_text_field","include_in_all":false},"title":{"type":"string","store":true,"fields":{"sort":{"type":"string","analyzer":"sortable_truncated_text_field"}},"analyzer":"generic_text_field","include_in_all":false},"twitter_in_reply_to_status_id":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"twitter_in_reply_to_user":{"type":"string","store":true,"analyzer":"lowercase_keyword","include_in_all":false},"twitter_in_reply_to_user_id":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"twitter_mentioned_user":{"type":"string","store":true,"analyzer":"lowercase_keyword","include_in_all":false},"twitter_mentioned_user_id":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"twitter_quoted_status_id":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"twitter_quoted_user":{"type":"string","store":true,"analyzer":"lowercase_keyword","include_in_all":false},"twitter_quoted_user_id":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"twitter_retweet_of_status_id":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"twitter_retweeted_user":{"type":"string","store":true,"analyzer":"lowercase_keyword","include_in_all":false},"twitter_retweeted_user_id":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"twitter_status_id":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"twitter_user":{"type":"string","store":true,"analyzer":"lowercase_keyword","include_in_all":false},"twitter_user_id":{"type":"long","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"typology":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"uri_hash":{"type":"short","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"url":{"type":"string","store":true,"term_vector":"with_positions","analyzer":"url_text_field","include_in_all":false}}},"annotation":{"include_in_all":false,"_parent":{"type":"myitem","fielddata":{"loading":"eager_global_ordinals"}},"_routing":{"required":true},"properties":{"category":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"category_annotations":{"type":"nested","include_in_root":true,"include_in_all":false,"properties":{"category":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"category_value":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"creation_time":{"type":"date","store":true,"format":"date_time","include_in_all":false},"is_automatic":{"type":"boolean","store":true},"rule_id":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"tone":{"type":"short","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"user_id":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false}}},"category_value":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"client":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"creation_time":{"type":"date","store":true,"format":"date_time","include_in_all":false},"draft":{"type":"boolean","store":true},"entity":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"is_automatic":{"type":"boolean","store":true},"project":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"publication_date":{"type":"date","store":true,"format":"date_time","include_in_all":false},"rule_id":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"user_id":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false}}},"project_category_annotation":{"include_in_all":false,"_parent":{"type":"status","fielddata":{"loading":"eager_global_ordinals"}},"_routing":{"required":true},"properties":{"annotation_rule":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"category":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"category_value":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"creation_time":{"type":"date","store":true,"format":"date_time","include_in_all":false},"origin":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false}}},"status":{"include_in_all":false,"_parent":{"type":"myitem","fielddata":{"loading":"eager_global_ordinals"}},"_routing":{"required":true},"properties":{"auto_status":{"type":"byte","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"client":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"confidence":{"type":"float","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"control_item":{"type":"boolean","store":true},"creation_time":{"type":"date","store":true,"format":"date_time","include_in_all":false},"origin":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"project":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"publication_date":{"type":"date","store":true,"format":"date_time","include_in_all":false},"reason":{"type":"short","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"sample_rule":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"status":{"type":"integer","store":true,"include_in_all":false},"validated":{"type":"boolean","store":true}}}},"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":"1","mapper":{"dynamic":"false"},"creation_date":"1482908398811","analysis":{"filter":{"sortable_truncate":{"length":"10","type":"truncate"},"spanish_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","language":"light_spanish"},"spanish_stop":{"type":"stop","stopwords":"_spanish_"},"custom_icu_folding":{"type":"icu_folding","unicodeSetFilter":"[^åäöÅÄÖñÑ]"}},"analyzer":{"url_text_field":{"filter":["lowercase"],"pattern":"#|&|\\+|\\,|-|\\.|/|:|\\;|=|\\?|_","type":"pattern","stopwords":["http","https","ftp","www"],"tokenizer":"keyword"},"sortable_truncated_text_field":{"filter":["standard","lowercase","sortable_truncate","custom_icu_folding"],"char_filter":["html_strip"],"type":"custom","tokenizer":"keyword"},"spanish_unstemmed":{"filter":["lowercase"],"char_filter":["html_strip"],"type":"custom","stopwords":"_none_","tokenizer":"standard"},"lowercase_keyword":{"filter":["lowercase"],"type":"custom","tokenizer":"keyword"},"generic_text_field":{"filter":["standard","lowercase","custom_icu_folding"],"char_filter":["html_strip"],"type":"custom","tokenizer":"standard"},"spanish_html_strip":{"filter":["lowercase","spanish_stop","spanish_stemmer"],"char_filter":["html_strip"],"type":"custom","tokenizer":"standard"},"sortable_text_field":{"filter":["standard","lowercase","custom_icu_folding"],"char_filter":["html_strip"],"type":"custom","tokenizer":"keyword"}}},"number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"j3gp_JcIR6q8HyLUT4sSfg","version":{"created":"2020199"}}},"warmers":{}}}
```

However, I want to obtain the data from the mapping `myitem`:

```
curl -XGET 'http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:9200/news_abc/myitem'
```

Error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No feature for name [myitem]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No feature for name [myitem]"},"status":400}
```

Comment: Try this -

curl -XGET 'http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:9200/news_abc/_search?pretty'
This will get you a "_source" field in the json response. This "_source" document will contain the "myitem" field and its values.

Then, you can use filters and aggregations to get all values in that field using the "-d" parameter for curl.

Comment: @PrateekParanjpe: It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

curl -XGET 'XXX.XX.XX.XX:9200/news_abc/_search?pretty';

This will get you a "_source" field in the json response. This "_source" document will contain the "myitem" field and its values.

Then, you can use filters and aggregations to get all values in that field using the "-d" parameter for curl.